# gatsbyjs - how to use bootstrap 4 with gatsbyjs 2

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I am new to `gatsbyjs`. Followed all the tutorials and started working with Saasland template to create a website with `gatsbyjs`. I've install bootstrap with npm. The template has following vendor specific dependencies:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--icon font css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icon/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/font-awesome/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flaticon/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/animation/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/animation/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/magnify-pop/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/elagent/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
```

In `gatsby` I am using bootstraptheme https://www.npmjs.com/package/typography-theme-bootstrap typography as below:

```
import Typography from "typography"
import bootstrapTheme from 'typography-theme-bootstrap'

const typography = new Typography(bootstrapTheme)

export default typography
```

This works fine. Now, when I try to use, for example, `nav` from template which is as below I am getting errors in webpack for bootstrap specific classes.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg menu_one menu_four">
```

I've copied and pasted template specific css into `layout.module.css`.

So, **How do I use `bootstrap` with `gatsbyjs` ? How do I use other vendor specific dependencies from template to `gatsbyjs` ? Should I import `bootstrap.min.css` into `layout.module.css` on top of template specific css classes ?**

Comment: https://github.com/jaxx2104/gatsby-starter-bootstrap

Comment: @ksav is there anyway to avoid using another package ? as boostrap package is already installed.

Comment: Since Gatsby uses React, you won't be able to use the "class" attribute - try "className" instead

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add a **Bootstrap** dependency with `npm install bootstrap`. Then, create a `gatsby-browser.js` file at the root of your app. Finally, import Bootstrap with `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: It worked, however It overrides the style of my theme, is there a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got Bootstrap to work with Gatsby.

`npm install bootstrap@3.3.7`      [I wanted to use bootstrap 3]

In the page you want to load Bootstrap, import it the following way

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use this I receive the following error:

Failed to compile
./src/pages/home.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/home/equidev/public_html/dr/equisphere/src/pages'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.